# How to check if 2 images are similar with respect to a reference object?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In my application I want to check whether an image taken has the same reference object that a previous image had. 
For eg. I capture an image having a pole besides an open land and say after few months I capture standing at the same position and I now get an image of the pole and some building coming up. I want to check if the images are similar in this respect.

Comment: Why do you need to check if its same object? You should already have reference to the object which shouldn't change

Answer (score 0):

We cannot check object , but other way is that we can save our image to the drawable and then we can check the bytes of the image , if bytes are same then image is same

Try to compare with bytes or pixel is the only way that generally works.

```
drawable1.bytesEqualTo(drawable2) 
drawable1.pixelsEqualTo(drawable2) 
bitmap1.bytesEqualTo(bitmap1) 
bitmap1.pixelsEqualTo(bitmap2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option A**: Calculate a simplified histogram (8 bits). Sort your images by histogram similarity.

I used this in a image-processing class. It's a pretty forgiving way to compare images. Small changes in lighting or orientation won't break the comparison. You can even flip the image 90° or 180°.

I still have the code, even if it was matlab, it may be helpful:

```
// image to compare:
QueryPicture = imread(strcat('E:\Users\user98\Images\',num2str(floor(result/10)),num2str(mod(result,10)),'.jpg'));

sums = zeros(50,2);

 h = zeros(64,50);

 // do a simpified histogram:
 for n=1:50
    img=double(imread(strcat('E:\Users\user98\Images\',num2str(floor(n/10)),num2str(mod(n,10)),'.jpg')));
    for i=1:200
         for j=1:200         
             x1 = bitshift(img(i,j,1), -6);
             x2 = bitshift(img(i,j,2), -6) * 4;
             x3 = bitshift(img(i,j,3), -6) * 16;
             x = x1 + x2 + x3;
             h(x+1, n) = (h(x+1, n) + 1);
         end
    end
 end

// compare histograms:
for n=1:50
    tmpVec = zeros(64,1);
    for i=1:64
        tmpVec(i) = abs(h(i,n) - h(i,result));
    end

    for j=1:64 
       sums(n,1) = sums(n,1)+tmpVec(j);
    end
    sums(n,2) = n;
end
sortedImages = sortrows(sums,1)



// Show compare-image:
subplot(2,3,1); image(uint8(QueryPicture));
// show 3 best matches for compare-image:
sortedImages(1);
sortedImages(2);
sortedImages(3);
img1=double(imread(strcat('E:\Users\user98\Images\',num2str(floor(sortedImages(2,2)/10)),num2str(mod(sortedImages(2,2),10)),'.jpg')));
img2=double(imread(strcat('E:\Users\user98\Images\',num2str(floor(sortedImages(3,2)/10)),num2str(mod(sortedImages(3,2),10)),'.jpg')));
img3=double(imread(strcat('E:\Users\user98\Images\',num2str(floor(sortedImages(4,2)/10)),num2str(mod(sortedImages(4,2),10)),'.jpg')));

subplot(2,3,4); image(uint8(img1));
subplot(2,3,5); image(uint8(img2));
subplot(2,3,6); image(uint8(img3));
```

**Option B:**:

Use the gps data from the image (exif) if available.

**Option C:**:

Google Lens is an app that can classify images and detect objects.